# Identify mapped fields in automapper

Tags: automapper

I want to find all the fields affected after executing the `Mapper.Map`.
How to identify the fields that were actually mapped after Mapping has taken place using Automapper?

Comment: For what purpose? I don't get the idea behind what you are looking for.

Comment: Want to identify all the fields that were actually updated from a given process

Comment: I mean if you have them, what will you do with them?

Comment: Update the database tables accordingly